# Bind 'select' element size to array length

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a select element that is being filled with anywhere from 20-50 names.  Currently, the number of elements being displayed is 3 and there is a scrollbar that allows the user to scroll up and down to make the desired selections.  Is there a way I can bind the array's length to the size property as well as include an if statement?  For example, if I have less than 25 names set the size of the select box to 10, otherwise set the size of the select box to 20.

```
<select size="3" multiple="multiple" id="selectMultiple" style="margin: 5px 0px; width:50%">
     <option ng-repeat="value in scope.Names">{{value.Name}}</option>
</select>
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: Define a function that would return size value and call it using ng-size="{{functionName}}" instead of size attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use interpolation operator

```
<select size="{{size}}" multiple="multiple" id="selectMultiple" style="margin: 5px 0px; width:50%">
     <option ng-repeat="value in scope.Names">{{value.Name}}</option>
</select>
```

in your controller

```
$scope.size=($scope.Names.length>25?20:10);
```

You can also use `ng-size` attribute like

```
<select ng-size="{{size}}" multiple="multiple" id="selectMultiple" style="margin: 5px 0px; width:50%">
     <option ng-repeat="value in scope.Names">{{value.Name}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: If the size property or ng-size directive did not work for you, check out the ng-attr-size property mentioned by Pankaj Parkar below.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `{{}}` interpolation directive inside `size` attribute, or better would be use [**`ng-attr-size`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions#usage) directive to create `size` attribute with its value.

```
ng-attr-size="{{getSize(Names)}}"
```

I guess `scope.Names` should be `Names`

```
function getSize(collection){
   return collection && (Names.length > 25? 20: 10);
}
```

Comment: Looks better :) +1

Comment: In one html file that I had, the above answer worked, yet in a second html file that I had it did not.  Utilizing the ng-attr-size property is what fixed my issue there.  I'm not sure what the difference between the two files is, but if ng-size is not working I would use the ng-attr-size property.

Comment: @SQLandJavaLearner I didn't find any documentation on `ng-size` though, even documentation is mentioned to use [`ngAttrSize`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions#usage)